# Как правильно написать записку в храме: об упокоении или о упокоении?

Tags: правила, предлоги

Как правильно написать записку в храме? О**б** упокоении или о упокоении? Меня там уверяют, что заглавие записки "Об упокоении" - неправильный вариант. Буква **б** зачёркивается.

Comment: Лариса, а не мог ли бы попросить их обосновать свою точку зрения. Раз уж они сердобольно уверяют вас, то пусть обоснуют.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то согласно правилам нужно " об упокоении". Даже в словаре "об упокоении" . [Орфографический словарь](http://orthographic.academic.ru/84037/%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

[Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/bts/) Молиться об упокоении кого-л.

Answer (score 2):

Странно. Хотя, если честно, я вообще всегда пишу "За упокой" и "За здравие" (или чаще "О здравии"), и никто меня еще за это не ругал. Более того, не придираются, если имена написаны в современных формах, например, Алексей, а не Алексий.
Может, конечно, в церковно-славянском предлога "об" нет - тут я не специалист, сказать не могу, но все равно - придираются. Есть при храмах часто такие тетеньки, которые не Богу молятся, а только и следят, кто как свечку поставил и кто где стоит. Не обращайте внимания.
А насчет предлога "об" послушаю версии специалистов.

Answer (score 2):

Нас учили в школе, что если на стыке слов две гласные, нужно разделять её согласным звуком, это легче произносится.
Таким образом "Об упокоении".

Comment: Ну, при чем тут "легче произносится"? Просто так ПРАВИЛЬНО! Без вариантов.

Comment: При том, что правило обосновывается тем, что упрощает речевой оборот.

Answer (score 2):

В художественных текстах встречаются оба варианта:

"Потом он пошел в церковь служить панихиду и, помолившись о упокоении души новопреставленной Акилины, решил поскорее жениться" (М. Горький).

"Много слыхал я простых и вместе глубоких воспоминаний, сопровождаемых слезами и крестным знамением об упокоении души его" (С. Т. Аксаков).

В церковной литературе также встречаются оба варианта, в том числе церковные записки, подаваемые "О здравии" или "О упокоении"/об упокоении". Можно предположить, что  "о упокоении" более соответствует церковным канонам.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) ОБ - предлог, употребляется вместо "О", в частности,  перед словами, начинающимися с гласной, например: об армии, об искусстве.

2) Предлог/приставка "О" используется по отношению к действию, которое  охватывает весь предмет;  он чаще применяется в книжной речи или используется в переносном значении.  "ОБ" имеет аналогичное значение,  но при этом чаще используется в прямом смысле и в разговорной речи.  Сравнить: охватить предмет - обхватить руками дерево.

Comment: София, а исходя из чего вы можете предположить, что правильнее "О упокоении"? В церковных текстах встречаются оба варианта.

Comment: Думаю, что это соблюдение старых книжных традиций, ведь для обычной речи такой предлог перед гласной неудобен. Можно предположить, что вариант с предлогом "ОБ" в церковных текстах просто допускается.

Comment: Мне кажется, что О упокоении" это просто окказионализм, который прочно проник в церковный лексикон и теперь употребляется наряду с предлогом  об. Хотя сейчас уже трудно , на мой взгляд , определить: что правильно , а что - нет.

Comment: С точки зрения светской орфографии, это неправильно. Церковные традиции  я не взялась бы комментировать, здесь нужен специалист.

Comment: Подробнее об этом предлоге -[на Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=ko_dnu)

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю простой выход:
если вы сами пишете на записочке название треб, то пишите по правилам "Об упокоении", а если записка уже содержит напечатанное "О упокоении", то примите без нареканий.

Answer (score 1):

А кто уверяет-то?
Если кто-то из обычных прихожан, то не обращайте внимания.
Нет более упрямых и несознательных существ, чем необразованные, но рьяные нововоцерковленные миряне. А коли они еще и всей общиной начинают правила устанавливать - туши свечи.

А если клир, или, избави Господь, сам батюшка, то они ведут себя по меньшей мере странно.
В церковнославянском - да, предлога *об* нет. Но вы-то записку подаете ***на русском***. А они уж пусть уж переводят.

Answer (score 0):

В нашем храме придирок по написанию записок нет, но в лавке всегда подскажут. И спорить с правилами грешно, нужно прислушиваться и просто смиренно исполнять. А если даже подскажут те же прихожане, то ничего страшного не произойдет, обижаться тоже грех, нужно все постигать и, заходя в храм, самим нужно быть уважительным, видя, что идет служба, не ходить по храму, а стоять и молиться, дожидаясь конца службы. Тогда можно ходить по храму, и то не топая каблуками, всегда помнить, что зашли не в сарай.